# How to implement jquery-datatables:1.7.5 plugin in my grails application

Tags: jquery, grails, datatable

I want to use org.grails.plugins:jquery-datatables:1.7.5 in my grails application.

As a beginner i added the following lines to BuildConfig.groovy

> ```
>   compile "org.grails.plugins:jquery-datatables:1.7.5"
>   compile "org.grails.plugins:jquery-ui:1.10.4"
> ```

in Config.groovy

```
grails.plugin.datatables.jQueryUI = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = 
[ 
'/dataTables/getData/**':     ['permitAll'],
'/dataTables/getReport/**':   ['permitAll']
]
```

in main.gsp

```
  <g:javascript library="jquery" plugin="jquery" />
  <r:require module="jquery-ui"/>
  <g:javascript library="application" />
```

Now How Can i implement this datatable in my specified GSP?

Answer (score 0):

the grails plugins just provides the necessary .js files.
you should embed them in your html dom (e.g. inside the head tags in your layout gsp) via the tag

```
<jqDT:resources/>
```

or, if you want to use asset pipeline, place the necessary require statements in your application.css/.js

as soon as you have the .js files included, you create a datatable via javascript just as you would if you included the lib by hand:

```
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    ...
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
  });
</script>
```

just have a look at https://datatables.net for lots of documentation and examples